# Large MySQL table with very slow select

Tags: mysql

I have a large table in MySQL (running within MAMP) it has 28 million rows and its 3.1GB in size. Here is its structure

```
    CREATE TABLE `termusage` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `termid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gprsup` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gprsdown` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `termid_idx` (`termid`),
  KEY `date_idx` (`date`),
  KEY `cost_type_idx` (`cost_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `termusage_cost_type_cost_type_cost_code` FOREIGN KEY (`cost_type`) REFERENCES `cost_type` (`cost_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `termusage_termid_terminal_id` FOREIGN KEY (`termid`) REFERENCES `terminal` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28680315 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the output from SHOW TABLE STATUS :

```
Name,Engine,Version,Row_format,Rows,Avg_row_length,Data_length,Max_data_length,Index_length,Data_free,Auto_increment,Create_time,Update_time,Check_time,Collation,Checksum,Create_options,Comment    
'termusage', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Compact', '29656469', '87', '2605711360', '0', '2156920832', '545259520', '28680315', '2011-08-16 15:16:08', NULL, NULL, 'latin1_swedish_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

Im trying to run the following select statement :

```
    select u.id from termusage u
    where u.date between '2010-11-01' and '2010-12-01'
```

it takes 35 minutes to return to result (approx 14 million rows) - this is using MySQL Worksbench.

I have the following MySQL config setup :

```
Variable_name              Value
bulk_insert_buffer_size    8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   1
innodb_buffer_pool_size    3221225472
innodb_change_buffering    all
innodb_log_buffer_size     8388608
join_buffer_size               131072
key_buffer_size            8388608
myisam_sort_buffer_size    8388608
net_buffer_length              16384
preload_buffer_size            32768
read_buffer_size               131072
read_rnd_buffer_size       262144
sort_buffer_size               2097152
sql_buffer_result              OFF
```

Eventually im trying to run a larger query - that joins a couple of tables and groups some data, all based on the variable - customer id -

```
select c.id,u.termid,u.cost_type,count(*) as count,sum(u.cost) as cost,(sum(u.gprsup) + sum(u.gprsdown)) as gprsuse,sum(time_to_sec(u.duration)) as duration 
from customer c
inner join terminal t
on (c.id = t.customer)
inner join termusage u
on (t.id = u.termid)
where c.id = 1 and u.date between '2011-03-01' and '2011-04-01' group by c.id,u.termid,u.cost_type
```

This returns a maximum of 8 rows (as there are only 8 separate cost_types - but this query runs OK where there are not many (less than 1 million) rows in the termusage table to calculate - but takes forever when the number of rows in the termusage table is large - how can I reduce the select time.

Data is added to the termusage table once a month from CSV files using LOAD DATA method - so it doesn't need to be quite so tuned for inserts.

EDIT : Show explain on main query :

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,c,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,8,const,1,"Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,SIMPLE,u,ALL,"termid_idx,date_idx",NULL,NULL,NULL,29656469,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,t,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,customer_idx",PRIMARY,8,wlnew.u.termid,1,"Using where"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're asking two questions - correct?

The most likely reason the first query is taking so long is because it's IO-bound. It takes a long time to transfer 14 million records from disk and down the wire to your MySQL work bench.

Have you tried putting the second query though "explain"? Yes, you only get back 8 rows - but the SUM operation may be summing millions of records.

I'm assuming the "customer" and "terminal" tables are appropriately indexed? As you're joining on the primary key on termusage, that should be really quick...

Comment: The first query is just to demonstrate the slowness of the table - i dont actually run that query i only run the final one ... I have added a show explain on the final query to the question - hope that might provide some answers ?

Comment: Cool. The explain shows that the query is not using an index on the termusage table, which explains a lot...you could try creating an index on both the termid and date columns.

Comment: OK - Im in no way an expert on MySQL - im more of a PHP / Java / Front end developer - im trying to find a good resource for interpreting the explain results - do you have one ? or point me in the right direction ?

Comment: @Nevile K - create an index with 2 columns ? or create 2 indexes (1 for each column) sorry !?!?

Comment: Create an index for two columns - you've already got indices on each separate column. 

"Create index test on termusage(termid, date)" should do the trick...

Comment: Its already got an index on each column so I assume you meant an index of both columns - its being created now ... MySQL Docs on the web are very poor when it comes to the results of the show explain command - unless im browsing the wrong section -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Yeah, the MySQL query optimizer is a bit of a dark horse. This is where to look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html - but it's heavy going.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - im going to wait until the index is created before I celebrate ... I will have a read of the link you posted while i wait - thanks again .. (will mark your answer the correct one when it works !)

Comment: That index you suggested (termid,date) didnt change the explain results - I created another index (termid,cost_type) and that fixed the problem .... 30 seconds now instead of 30 mins ..... Thanks for your help with the explain command - its now my best friend :-)

Comment: +1 for `SUM` warning.  On the fly calculations in SQL are SLOOOOOOOOOOOOOW.  Use the server (PHP, .net, RoR, C++).  That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the where clause restricting by date and instead put an IF statement in the select so that if the date is within these boundaries, the value is returned otherwise a zero value is returned.   The SUM will then of course only sum values which lie in this range as all others will be zero.

It sounds a bit nonsensical to fetch more rows than you need but we observed recently on an Oracle DB that this made quite a huge improvement.   Of course it will be dependent on many other factors but it might be worth a try.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - i will see how long a select statement runs without the dates just as soon as the index (from Pelshoff's comment) finishes being created !

Comment: Pelshoff deleted his answer !

Comment: @Pelshoff - no probs ... there are no wrong answers ... it made me think about which way the index was setup !

Comment: Well, I'm glad it did something :p

Comment: It's always a good idea to think about indices - you might like to try creating one index that contains all the columns in the group by clause, in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You may also think about breaking down the table into years or months. So you have a termusage_2010, termusage_2011, ... or something like this.

Not a very nice solution, but seeing your table is quite large it might be usefull on a smaller server.